# How can I load a Gigapixel image as a material in SceneKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I’m trying to create an AR image to project on a wall from a Gigapixel image. Obviously Xcode crashes if I try to load the image as a material. Is there an efficient way to load only parts of the image that the user is looking at?
I'm using Swift 4.

Comment: I guess a combination of tiling and mipmapping could work here.

Answer (score 0):

This may not do exactly what you want, and you might need to roll-your-own way of parsing and passing data between Core Animation and SceneKit, but this is native, and is designed to handle large images and texture data sources, and feed them out asynchronously, and/or on a demand based basis:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/catiledlayer